# Firewall settings for VLC (streaming)

Tags: vlc, firewall

I'm watching online TV with VLC and http://mafreebox.freebox.fr/freeboxtv/playlist.m3u.
Does anybody know which ports and protocol must be enabled in my firewall settings? I've been searching on the videolan website, unsuccessfully so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the link provided is DEAD

Comment: The link is ok, it is the link to the playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, but you can install [firestarter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/firestarter/), where you can disable firewall or see active connections. It's not best firewall manager, but it's easiest way to see active connections. After installing (most options are OK by default, you will see window look similar to this:

[image: Firestarter window]

Click on Active connections, and you will see connection name, destination, description and port.

Comment: This doesn;t really answer the question. If you added how to use Firestarter's logs to determine what ports must be opened, that would be better.

Comment: Did I miss off something? I was stuck in the chapter where "Firestarter is deprecated" and all my answers referring to Firestarter were downvoted.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is deprecated, but I don't know about any other way to answer this question without using terminal.

Comment: I don't mind using the command line.

Comment: @kubahaha : I installed Firestarter and was able to see outboung traffic (RTSP protcol) which VLC was sending to one host. I then added a rule to allow inbound traffic from this host and it worked fine (although I had to use port range instead of port 554, so I still must have missed something.) Thanks!

Comment: I am pleased that I could help. Also you can choose best answer by clicking in star on the left of solution.